Azure Function App doesn't forward logs to AppInsight
I'm encountering an issue where Azure Function App isn't forwarding logs to AppInsight. I've checked the file system logs on the function app, and they're working fine and complete. Also, I'm sure that my APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY is configured correctly. Moreover, this only happens in the dev environment; in higher environments, it works fine. I'm using Terraform to create resources. Do you know what possibilities could lead to this issue? (network, role, configuration, etc.) Thanks a lot.
screenshot filesystem log

My host.json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "always",
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information",
      "Host": "Error",
      "Function": "Information",
      "Host.Aggregator": "Information"
    }
  }
}

Startup.cs
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Services
        .AddLogging(lb =>
        {
            lb.AddApplicationInsightsWebJobs(options =>
            {
                options.InstrumentationKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY");
            });
        })
    // Already try AddLogging()

}

my csproj
 <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>  
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventGrid" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Kafka" Version="3.8.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="4.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.1.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\EventBroker.Application\EventBroker.Application.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\EventBroker.Infrastructure\EventBroker.Infrastructure.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>


Please share your .csproj file. Also please share your function code.

You are having issue in getting logs when the app is running locally?

You are setting Instrumentation key from Environment variable.Does your local app has environment variable set?

What Azure Function kind are you using (In-process or Isolated)? What .NET version?

Hi @Harshitha,
I have already shared .csproj file. I just implement log.LogInformation in function code.
I have issue the log that is not forwarded to appinsight. But I already check the filesystem log in function. It work properly

Hi @VladDX - I use In-process and .Net 6

Make sure you are able to get the Instrumentation key locally.Try to print the value locally and check.

Yep, I have tried logging the Instrumentation key
 log.LogInformation($"Key: {Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY")}");
It logged to filesystem log properly

You don't need to configure DI for Application Inisghts.

Application Insights is added by Azure Functions automatically.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#logging-services

You just need to configure Application Insights by using either of:

APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#applicationinsights_connection_string

APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#appinsights_instrumentationkey



Already tried this. But the log is still not forwarded to App Insight

In addition to Vlad DX's answer check the below steps.

Configure the Application Insights from Connected Services.



Instrumentation key is stored in Secrets.json file locally.


As mentioned by Vlad DX, you don`t need to add Dependency Injection for Application Insights.

I did not add any Startup file, I have tried to run the default Function App and log messages locally.

Default host.json worked for me.


My host.json file:
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            }
        }
    }
}

My .csproj file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <ApplicationInsightsResourceId>/subscriptions/****/resourceGroups/****/providers/microsoft.insights/components/FunctionApp1</ApplicationInsightsResourceId>
    <UserSecretsId>****</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
  
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />  
  
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>



You can see the traces requested from localhost.


Deployed Function Output:


@tatea99 - Are you able to log traces ?

Can you check out this question as well?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79016060/some-logs-doesnt-reach-appinsight-with-isolated-function-app

Sure..will check and let you know
