Some logs don't reach appinsights with isolated function app
I got a C# Azure function app and it uses an ILogger to log to app insight.
Until recently, the function app was implemented using .NET 6 and everything was fine. I then converted it to use .NET 8 and it's now dotnet-isolated.
Ever since the change, it seems like I'm losing log entries whenever I'm logging inside loops.. I do see all logs which are not inside loops, but it seems like after the conversion, it's like it can't handle fast logging to app insight? What can be done to solve it?
CSProj file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">


<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enabled</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="local.settings.json" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityModel" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="RT.Comb" Version="4.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="SharpZipLib" Version="1.4.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="8.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="8.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.23.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.3.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Migrations\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

This is my host.json:
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "functionTimeout": "02:00:00",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Trace"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": false
      }
    }
  }
}


is it configured as per documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide?tabs=windows#logging? by default dotnet isolated min log level is warning: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide?tabs=windows#managing-log-levels

@Thomas The logger instance is retrieved by a DI like is described at the beginning. However, I don't use any special package for appinsights or configure the logging in the code at all (except for the host.json). The function app is created by a Terrafrom plan which passes an instrumentation key as a parameter

@CodeMonkey Sure..will check and let you know.Please share your configuration and .csproj file.

@Harshitha Added the csproj file

@CodeMonkey for isolated, you need to configure app insights manually: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide?tabs=windows#application-insights

@Thomas but if that's the case, then why most logs DO appear in app insights (those which are not inside loops)?

if you can paste some code so we can reproduce that would be great. you may have sampling enable as well ?

I don't use ANY code to configure logging. I just use whatever instance of ILogger I get from the DI. And I actually do have sampling enabled and as we speak I'm trying to prepare a new image with sampling disabled to see if it helps

@CodeMonkey can you share your program.cs code and function.cs code.

seems like its not the sampling either

@Thomas After further investigations, it seems like the issue is with the log level. I do see information level logs, but not trace logs. I have added my host.json file in which we can see that the default log level is trace..

I created a sample .NET 6 Azure Function App and then migrated it to .NET 8, can successfully see the Application Insights logs from the loop.

While migrating from .NET 6 to .NET 8, we may encounter issues due to NuGet packages not being installed correctly. So, ensure that the packages are upgraded accordingly.
I've referred this doc for migration.

I've added the below logic to print log messages from 1 to 1000 in a loop.
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    _logger.LogInformation($"Logging message number {i + 1}");
    await Task.Delay(10);
}
var response = req.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);

Function1.cs:
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace MyFunctionApp
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;
        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
        [Function("Function1")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseData> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation($"Logging message number {i + 1}");
                await Task.Delay(10);
            }
            var response = req.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
            response.WriteString("Welcome to Azure Functions!");
            return response;
        }
    }
}

Program.cs:
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
    })
    .Build();
await host.RunAsync();

.csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>   <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>             
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.23.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.2.0" />     
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.8" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights" Version="2.22.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <None Update="host.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>
        <None Update="local.settings.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
            <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        </None>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>

local.settings.json:
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING": "<Connection-string>"
  }
}

Output:

Application Insights logs:


I'm not using the app insights nugets. Maybe that's the problem

After further investigations, it seems like the issue is with the log level. I do see information level logs, but not trace logs. I have added my host.json file in which we can see that the default log level is trace...

By default it just log the Error not any other log. We need to add the settings to ensure it logs everything or what we need.
Sharing my code which I added to log information logs also.
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        CompositionRoot.Configure(services);
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    }).ConfigureLogging((context, logging) =>
    {
        logging.ClearProviders();

        if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_FUNCTION_ENVIRONMENT") == "Development")
            logging.AddConsole(); //NOSONAR

        logging.AddApplicationInsights(options => { });
        logging.AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("", LogLevel.None);
        logging.AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("<NameSpace>", LogLevel.Information);
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();

